# Displaying images in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a webpage that I want to dynamically display content depending on the path of the page. For example, I may want `http://www.page.php?input=red` or maybe I'll want `http://www.page.php?input=blue`. In both cases, the actual content is located in `./$dir/`.

I've got the gist of this down, but I can't for the life of me figure out images. I have an image in each directory at `./$dir/subdir/images/sample.png`. How do I output HTML that dynamically alters the image element?

Here is sample code to demonstrate my question.

```
<html>
    <?php
        $dir = $_GET["input"];
        $img = imagecreatefrompng("./$dir/subdir/images/sample.png");
    ?>
    <body>
        <img src="???" alt="sample image" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to display `./red/subdir/images/sample.png` when I have `input=red`, `./blue/subdir/images/sample.png` when `input=blue`, etc.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Edit:
I don't even know if I can store an image into a variable as seen on line 4. I'm really new to PHP.

Comment: what is `imagecreatefrompng()`? Just make the path in a variable and set it as the src. `<img src="<?php echo $ptah; ?>" />

Comment: I Googled a bit and found imagecreatefrompng(); I imagine this is a function inherent in PHP like explode() or etc.

Comment: But you don't need it, if you have the image already, just include it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only one image:

```
<img src="<?= $img ?>" alt="sample image" />
```

If loads of images, use an array.

I would also set the alt text on a database, pull it from there and write it the same way I suggested writing the src.

Just so you can understand:

```
<?= $img ?>
```

Does exactly the same thing as

```
<?php echo $img; ?>
```

Except with a bit more class.

edit: Typo on the indent made my code disappear.

Comment: recommended use `<?php echo $img ?>`, not all server enable `<?= ?>`

Comment: I knew some servers didn't accept `<? ?>`, but the `<?= ?>` I didn't know. Great tip.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!empty($_GET['input']) {
  $path = './'.$dir.'/subdir/images/sample.png';
  if (file_exists($path)) {
    print '<img src="'.$path.'" alt="sample image" />';
  }
}
```